# storage with Zend AuthService and android app

Tags: android, zend-framework2, httpurlconnection

I have a website using zend framework for the server side, the website run perfectly. I want to create an android app using this server to. My problem is on the authservice storage (this code is on the server and called by my app:

```
...
if ($authResult->isValid()) {
    $identity = $authResult->getIdentity();
    $authService->getStorage()->write($identity);
    ...
```

Then when I want to read the storage with (in controller):

```
$user = $this->identity()
```

or:

```
$authService->getStorage()->read();
```

the result is null each time...

to call the server I use HttpURLConnection in my app with the cookie manager.

Any clue what's wrong?

Comment: What adapter are you using with the ZF2 auth service?

Comment: `$authService = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Zend\Authentication\AuthenticationService');
                $adapter = $authService->getAdapter();`                 I notice this problem by calling a function that need the storage. But I tried another function that need it too, and this second one work ! So I suppose the error come from the module.config.php file (the two function are not in the same module)